# Why doesn't the BigUpload.php receive the $_POST value (savefolder) from this form?

Tags: php, html

This is from the HTML part of a PHP file:

```
<form action="inc/bigUpload.php?action=post-unsupported" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="bigUploadForm">
  <input type="text" id="savefolder" name="savefolder" value="987653210"/>
  <input type="file" id="bigUploadFile" name="bigUploadFile" />
  <input type="button" class="bigUploadButton" value="Start Upload" id="bigUploadSubmit" onclick="upload()" />
  <input type="button" class="bigUploadButton bigUploadAbort" value="Cancel" onclick="abort()" />
</form>
```

When I try to send the value where the file should be saved, it is not received in bigUpload.php. I have tried everything including:

```
if(isset($_POST['savefolder'])) {
    $saveFolder = $_POST['savefolder'];
}else{
    $saveFolder = 'all_other_files';
}
```

So regardless of what I put in the HTML form's text field, the file is placed in "all_other_files" folder.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post the part of upload() in your code

Comment: I can do it, but I don't think it'd help. Because the script is able to use the other $saveFolder variable.

Comment: OK, if you insist then please try this (1) remove onclick="upload()"; and (2) change <input type="button" to <input type="submit" , then see what happens

Comment: Thanks! It's a good solution and it seems to be working. I'm gonna work on it further and make the layout nicer!

Comment: Great. Have a nice day and happy coding :)